# Conditions for the inner bounds of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a matrix for which I have a function that picks an element of the array at random using the following code:

```
npcSelectShip() {
    let selectCol = () => {
        let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.npcSelectionField.length);
        let selectCell = () => {
            let cellIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.npcSelectionField[colIndex].length);
            if (this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty === false) {
                selectCell();
            } else {
                this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty = false;
                this.pickDirection(this.npcSelectionField, colIndex, cellIndex);
            }

        }

        selectCell();
    }

    selectCol();
}
```

After this I have another function that searches for the neighbors ( top, right, bottom and left ) of the randomly picked element, randomly picks a neighbor and changes a property:

```
    pickDirection(field, col, cell) {
       let neighbors = [];
       neighbors.push(
           field[col - 1][cell],
           field[col + 1][cell],
           field[col][cell - 1],
           field[col][cell + 1]
       );
       let randDir = () => {
           let randIndex = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)];
           if (randIndex.isEmpty === false) {
               randDir();
           } else {
               randIndex.isEmpty = false;
           }
       }

       randDir();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when the the randomly picked element has an index of either 0 or equal to the array lenght, because if it picks a neighbor at index-1 or index+1 its basically "out of bounds" and I get these errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined
```

Is there a way I can solve this without having to write a shitload of ifs and elses ?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and a default pattern, which returns an empty array.

In combination with `concat`, empty arrays acts as neutral values.

```
var neighbors = [].concat(
       (field[col - 1] || [])[cell] || [],
       (field[col + 1] || [])[cell] || [],
       (field[col] || [])[cell - 1] || [],
       (field[col] || [])[cell + 1] || []
   );
```

Or use a wrapper for accessing

```
function getCell(array, col, cell) {
    return (array[col] || [])[cell] || [];
}
```

usage

```
var neighbors = [].concat(
       getCell(field, col - 1, cell),
       getCell(field, col + 1, cell),
       getCell(field, col, cell - 1),
       getCell(field, col, cell + 1)
   );
```

> How it works
>
> ```
> (field[col - 1] || [])[cell] || []
> ```
>
> It tries to get the value of
>
> ```
>  field[col - 1]
> ```
>
> and if the value is `undefined`,
>
> ```
>  field[col - 1] || []
> ```
>
> it returns an empty array, with the locical [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) operator. What we get is either the array of `field[col - 1]` or an empty array `[]`.
>
> For the next index, we use the same pattern and check if
>
> ```
> (field[col - 1] || [])[cell]
> ```
>
> exists and if not then we take another empty array as result
>
> ```
> (field[col - 1] || [])[cell] || []
> ```
>
> Now we have either a truthy value, like an object or an empty array.
>
> This is necessary, because empty arrays are not added to an array with [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: Apologize for the late reply, but I want to understand how this works. Can you explain the logic behind (field[col - 1] || [])[cell] || [] ?

Comment: Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 2 options:

**First option:** Do not pickup in the first/last row/column:

```
npcSelectShip() {
    let selectCol = () => {
        let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.npcSelectionField.length-2)) +1;
        let selectCell = () => {
            let cellIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.npcSelectionField[colIndex].length-2)) +1;
            if (this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty === false) {
                selectCell();
            } else {
                this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty = false;
                this.pickDirection(this.npcSelectionField, colIndex, cellIndex);
            }

        }

        selectCell();
    }

    selectCol();
}
```

(see the "-2" and "+1" after `Math.random` functions call)

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (length-2)) +1;
```

Will take a number between `floor(0*(length-2)) +1 = 1` and `floor(1*(length-2)) +1 = length-1`

**Second option:** Make condition to not add as a neighbor something out of range

```
pickDirection(field, col, cell) {
   let neighbors = [];

   if(col-1 >= 0) {
       neighbors.push(field[col - 1][cell]);
   }
   if(col < field.length) {
       neighbors.push(field[col + 1][cell]);
   }
   if(cell-1 >= 0) {
       neighbors.push(field[col][cell -1]);
   }
   if(cell < field[col].length) {
       neighbors.push(field[col][cell +1]);
   }

   let randDir = () => {
       let randIndex = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)];
       if (randIndex.isEmpty === false) {
           randDir();
       } else {
           randIndex.isEmpty = false;
       }
   }

   randDir();
}
```

Comment: The second method makes sense, tho i stil get the TypeErrors on some ocassions

Comment: Can you check that your array does not contains any `undefined` values ? (Or maybe I've done a mistake but can't find it; maybe someone else will find my errors)

Comment: Yes, the neighbor array sometimes does contain one undefined value. What would be the cause of that ?

Comment: I don't know, I need to know how you build your `this.npcSelectionField` array for that :P

Comment: this.npcSelectionField doesnt contain any undefined values, its basically an outer array that contains arrays filled with objects.

Comment: Oh ok yes; and so the `field` is not containing `undefined` values too we are ok ? Maybe try with something like this: `if(col-1 >= 0 && field[col - 1][cell]) { neighbors.push(field[col - 1][cell]); }` (put in the if, after an `&&` the pushed value)